# when do you use chain rule with square root

Tags: calculus

If i have a question like this:
$$
\sqrt{3x}
$$
..differentiate...
$$
(3x)^{1/2}\rightarrow\frac12(3x)^{-1/2}
$$

Done using power rule...

Now i have seen examples where chain rule is applied too.. maybe i missed something..
$$
f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))\, g'(x).
$$
$$
\frac12(3x)^{-1/2} (3)
$$
derivative $3x$ is $3$.

$f(x) = \sqrt{3x}$. and... $g(x)=3x$.

Comment: It's less confusing to use a different letter for the argument of the "outer" function $f$.  A popular choice is $u$.  In your example, $f(u) = \sqrt{u}$, and not $\sqrt{3u}$ like you wrote.  If you had used a different letter, you might not have made that mistake.

Comment: that's how it was in the questions i get...

Comment: at robjohn how did you write math...

Comment: that's too bad, the question would have been more readable if they'd used "$u$" with $f$.

Comment: i think they are made to slightly trick you if you are not so skilled at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chain rule is required here: the derivative of $(3x)^{1/2}$ with respect to $x$ is not $\frac12(3x)^{-1/2}$, but rather

$$\frac12(3x)^{-1/2}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(3x)=\frac12(3x)^{-1/2}\cdot3=\frac32(3x)^{-1/2}\;.$$

This has nothing to do specifically with the square root function: the chain rule is **always** required when you’re differentiating a composite function, a ‘function of a function’, so to speak. Here you’re differentiating **not** the square root of $x$, but the square root of some function of $x$, and the derivative has to take that other function into account; the chain rule is the mechanism by which this is done.

Comment: how do you know it's required. And not just power rule. if i have x^3 the derivative of it would be 3x^2. So why x^1/2 is 1/2x (1).

Comment: @Techsin: Whenever you take the derivative of a composition of functions, you *must* use the chain rule. That's how you know it's required.

Comment: ok so by composite function you mean where something whole happens to x and everything around it. like 3x get its squareroot taken...so if it was like 3x^5 no chain rule but if like (3x^2)^2 than yes. I am just confused on what defines that its a function inside a function. x^2 not composite function.. (3x)^2 a composite function

Comment: @Techsin: I have added something to my answer that might be helpful.

Comment: @Techsin You might apply the power rule provided you want to get the derivative of a power of $x$, hence the name.  But $(3x)^{\text{something}}$ is no a power of $x$ but of $3x$ instead ...

Comment: @Techsin: Technically $3x^5$ **is** a composite function: first we raise $x^5$ power, and then we multiply that by $3$. Thus, at the outermost level it’s a product, and we could apply the product rule together with the chain rule to get $$3\frac{d}{dx}(x^5)+x^5\frac{d}{dx}(3)\;.$$ But the derivative of a constant is $0$, so this reduces to $$3\frac{d}{dx}(x^5)=3\cdot5x^4=15x^4\;.$$ Since this always happens when we multiply be a constant, we don’t bother: we just differentiate $cf(x)$ as $cf\,'(x)$. The function $(3x)^5$ is another matter: at the outermost level it’s a power, so we invoke ...

Comment: ... the power rule together with the chain rule to get $$5(3x)^4\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(3x)=5(3x)^4\cdot3=15(3x)^4=15\cdot3^4x^4=1215x^4\;.$$ Or we expand $(3x)^5$ to $3^5x^5=243x^5$ and treat it like $3x^5$, getting $5\cdot243x^4=1215x^4$. Observe that if we **didn’t** use the chain rule in the first version, we’d get $5(3x)^4$, which is $405x^4$, not the correct $1215x^4$. **Almost every differentiation rule that you learn includes the chain rule:** $\frac{d}{dx}(e^u)=e^u\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(u)$, $\frac{d}{dx}(u^n)=nu^{n-1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(u)$, $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln u)=\frac1u\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(u)$, ...

Comment: ... and so on, where in each case $u$ is any function of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
Now substitute $u=\sqrt{t}$ and $t=3x$. Then the power rule gives
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac12t^{-1/2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}=3
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}
&=3\cdot\frac12t^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac32\frac1{\sqrt{3x}}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Appealing to the Definition**

Consider the definition of the derivative applied to a composition:
$$
\begin{align}
f(g(x))'
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(g(x)+\color{#C00000}{g(x+h)-g(x)})-f(g(x))}{\color{#C00000}{g(x+h)-g(x)}}&&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\\
&=f'(g(x))&&g'(x)
\end{align}
$$
as long as $g$ is continuous at $x$, $g(x+h)-g(x)\to0$ as $h\to0$.

---

**Examples of Composition**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\color{#C00000}{x^2}\right)^2
&=2\left(\color{#C00000}{x^2}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\color{#C00000}{x^2}\\
&=2\left(x^2\right)2x\\
&=4x^3
\end{align}
$$
This is also $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^4=4x^3$.

You can even be overly pedantic and use the chain rule for the trivial composition
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin(\color{#C00000}{x})
&=\cos(\color{#C00000}{x})\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\color{#C00000}{x}\\
&=\cos(x)\cdot1\\
&=\cos(x)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: this is stuff i skipped in my math book and that's why i have trouble right now. But i know this is the underlying basic of it. I'll go over it later next week. But thanks. i don't get it right now.

Comment: now i am getting it...thanks..:D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "done by power rule".  Maybe you mean you've already done what I'm about to suggest: it's a lot easier to avoid the chain rule entirely and write $\sqrt{3x}$ as $\sqrt{3}*\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{3}*x^{1/2}$, unless someone tells you you *have* to use the chain rule.  I'll leave the rest to you.